# Wrong keys are printed using for..in on Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, properties

Consider this object: `var obj = {10: 0, 11: 1, 12: 2};`

Using the method `Object.keys(obj)`, you can see that `obj` has three keys: 10,11,12.

However, if you wanted to iterate over each key (for example, in order to get the value for each key), a standard for loop returns the correct keys, but the "for in" style does not. Does anyone know what's going on here? Is it possible to get the correct key names using "for in"?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7sm22kb/

Comment: Well, if you do `for key in Object.keys(obj)` like in your fiddle, then that loop will enumerate the *property names of the array* that `Object.keys` returns. You want `for key in obj`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific example, this is because `Object.keys` returns an array. `for ... in` and `Object.keys` do very similar things, so you're iterating over the keys *of the array of keys*, hence your problem.

You can see this by running:

```
var obj = {10: 0, 11: 1, 12: 2};
var keys = Object.keys(obj); // ['10', '11', '12'];
for (var key in keys) {
  console.log('Keys has', keys[key], 'at', key);
}
```

The proper equivalent using `for ... in` would be more like:

```
for(var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  }
}
```

You can see the additional complexity introduced here.

[`for ... in` (#12.6.4 in the spec)](https://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4) loops over all enumerable properties in the object, including ones inherited from the prototype, causing it to include a lot of stuff you may need to filter out. In the case of an array, it loops over the property names (i.e., array indices) of each item in the array. This is the second level of indirection you're running into problems with.

[`Object.keys` (#15.2.3.14 in the spec)](https://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.14) is defined to only retrieve keys from the object itself ("For each own enumerable property..."), saving you the need for that check.

When possible, prefer `Object.keys` in most cases, as it saves you the logic. If `[].forEach` is available, you can also use that:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log('Object has', obj[key], 'at', key);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect @jlewkovich wanted to use

```
for (key of Object.keys(obj)) {
```

rather than:

```
for (key in Object,keys(obj)) {
```

Notice *of* rather than *in*.  I say that because I found this page after making that mistake.

PS: I tried to add this as a comment, but don't have the reputation points, so please forgive a new answer where I think a comment would have been more appropriate. @ssube answered the question. This is an answer to a different question I think the author would have liked to ask.